# How to print xml file returned by the server

Tags: objective-c, xml, parsing

it is the first time i'm dealing with server communication trough HTTP requests and  in order to be sure of what i'm doing, and have "matter between my hands" i want to print the xml file that the server should return to me.
If someone could help me please :

Here is my code :

```
(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewDidAppear:animated];

if ([stories count] == 0) {
 NSString * l_api_key = @"********************************************";
    NSString * l_secret_key = @"******************************************";

    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[@myURLHERE stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]
                                                            cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
                                                        timeoutInterval:60.0];

    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [theRequest setValue:@"application/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [theRequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-unrlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
    [theRequest addValue:l_api_key forHTTPHeaderField: @"EMApikey"];
    [theRequest addValue:[self hmacsha1:l_api_key secret:l_secret_key] forHTTPHeaderField: @"EMRequestHash"];
    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
    NSLog(@"%@", theConnection);

    if( theConnection )
    {
        NSData *webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
        NSLog(@"%@", webData);
        //[self parseXMLFileAtURL:path];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"theConnection is NULL");
    }

    [theConnection release];
}

cellSize = CGSizeMake([newsTable bounds].size.width, 60);
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:theRequest
                           queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
               completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
{
    NSLog(@"%@", [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease]);
}];
```

it's more convenient than:

```
NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me twice today Cy-4AH you are very kind :) !

Answer (score 1):

You need to send the POST request and get back the response, see the example below :

```
//create the body
NSMutableData *postBody = [NSMutableData data];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<xml>"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<yourcode/>"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"</xml>"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

//post
[theRequest setHTTPBody:postBody];

//get response
NSHTTPURLResponse* urlResponse = nil;  
NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];  
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&error];  
NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Response Code: %d", [urlResponse statusCode]);
if ([urlResponse statusCode] >= 200 && [urlResponse statusCode] < 300) {
    NSLog(@"Response: %@", result);

            //here you get the response

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much aleroot i will dive into your answer and try it out :D.